# One statistical test for 4 subsets at a time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, bernoulli-process

Imagine a card player who is participating in a tournament with 4 different versions of one card game. The probabilities of winning by doing random actions in each type of game are the following: 0.61, 0.52, 0.44, and 0.35. Player statistics for all these types of games respectively are the following (games won/games played): 895/1080, 634/988, 315/1035, 523/975. How we can statistically test if the player is better in this game than a random guesser (not in each version of the game but in 4 altogether)?

My initial attempt was to use the Bernoulli trial with calculating what is the probability of a random guesser getting the same or higher result than a player and multiply it for all types of games to get the overall result. However, this method has an obvious logical mistake: in the third type of game, the player’s win rate is less than the winning probability, but when we calculate the probability of the random guesser getting the same or higher result it is still less than 1. So we will get a reduction of the random guesser’s probability to perform better than the player across all 4 types of games, even though the player performed worse than the random guesser was supposed to (as we expect the random guesser’s win ratio to be tending to win probability).

So I'm trying to find a method that will be correct to test if the player is better than a random guesser in all four versions of the game simultaneously.

Comment: Can a player play multiple games of the same different version? Or are there 1080 + 988 + 1035 + 975 units in your data?

Comment: @dimitriy there are 1080 + 988 + 1035 + 975 units in data

Comment: I think that there is something going wrong with you math. The probability that you see 315+ wins in 1035 games 3s is `sum(dbinom(315:1035, 1035, 0.44)) = pbinom(314, 1035, 0.44, lower.tail = FALSE) = 1`.

Comment: Per your comment below, "all four versions of the game simultaneously" does not mean a joint test of the four games. It means treating them as if they were on one. You should clarify that in your question to avoid confusion in case anyone else attempts this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Bayesian stab at this problem. This approach requires that you have the number of random games that got you 0.61, 0.52, 0.44, and 0.35. I will assume that you have historical data on random play for 1000 rounds for each game. For example, the random strategy won 610 times and lost 390 times in game 1, to get you 0.61. You can tweak the R code below with your numbers (capita Ls and Ws).

Let $\rho_{1}$ be the probability of a win in game 1 while playing randomly and $\pi_{1}$ be the probability of a win in game 1 using strategy. Before we see any data we think a loss is just as likely as a win. This corresponds to a uniform prior, which is the same as $Beta(1,1)$ distribution. The beta distribution is a suitable model for the random behavior of proportions. It has to parameters, $a$ and $b$, with the mean of $\frac{a}{a+b}$. So with a uniform prior, you believe that you win 50% of the time. You could have a diffrent prior, and this does not change the logic.

Now we get the data for game 1. Players of random version had 610 wins and 390 losses. Players of the other version had 895 wins and 185 losses. We update our priors, and our posteriors are that $\rho_{1} \sim Beta(610+1,390+1)$ and $\pi_{1} \sim Beta(895+1,185+1)$.

Now you can ask, what is the probability that strategy is better than random by at least $\delta$? In math, that's
$$\mathbf{Pr}(\rho_{1}  > \pi_{1} + \delta)$$

This is a gnarly integral, but you can use the following R function to calculate it:

```
# Pr(X > Y + d) where X~Beta(a,b) and Y~Beta(c,d)
beta.ineq <- function(a, b, c, d, delta)
{
  integrand <- function(x) { dbeta(x, a, b)*pbeta(x-delta, c, d) }
  integrate(integrand, delta, 1, rel.tol=1e-4)$value
}

# Uniform Prior = Beta(1,1)
prior_wins   <- 1
prior_losses <- 1

# Random Play Historical Data (May Want to Change Number of Games)
W1 <- 610
W2 <- 520
W3 <- 440 
W4 <- 350
L1 <- 1000 - W1
L2 <- 1000 - W1
L3 <- 1000 - W1
L4 <- 1000 - W1 

# Data on Wins w and Losses l for Games 1-4  
w1 <- 895
l1 <- 1080 - w1
w2 <- 634
l2 <- 988  - w2
w3 <- 315
l3 <- 1035 - w3
w4 <- 523
l4 <- 975  - w4
    
# Updated Posteriors with uniform prior = beta(1,1)
(Pr_btr_1 <- beta.ineq(w1 + prior_wins, l1 + prior_losses, W1 + prior_wins, L1 + prior_losses, delta=0))
(Pr_btr_2 <- beta.ineq(w2 + prior_wins, l2 + prior_losses, W2 + prior_wins, L2 + prior_losses, delta=0))
(Pr_btr_3 <- beta.ineq(w3 + prior_wins, l3 + prior_losses, W3 + prior_wins, L3 + prior_losses, delta=0))
(Pr_btr_4 <- beta.ineq(w4 + prior_wins, l4 + prior_losses, W4 + prior_wins, L4 + prior_losses, delta=0))
(Pr_btr_1*Pr_btr_2*Pr_btr_3*Pr_btr_4)
```

The last step calculates the overall probability across all 4 games by multiplying.

The output is:

```
> # Updated Posteriors with uniform prior = beta(1,1)
> (Pr_btr_1 <- beta.ineq(w1 + prior_wins, l1 + prior_losses, W1 + prior_wins, L1 + prior_losses, delta=0))
[1] 1
> (Pr_btr_2 <- beta.ineq(w2 + prior_wins, l2 + prior_losses, W2 + prior_wins, L2 + prior_losses, delta=0))
[1] 0.9991309
> (Pr_btr_3 <- beta.ineq(w3 + prior_wins, l3 + prior_losses, W3 + prior_wins, L3 + prior_losses, delta=0))
[1] 2.166106e-23
> (Pr_btr_4 <- beta.ineq(w4 + prior_wins, l4 + prior_losses, W4 + prior_wins, L4 + prior_losses, delta=0))
[1] 0.9953638
> (Pr_btr_1*Pr_btr_2*Pr_btr_3*Pr_btr_4)
[1] 2.15419e-23
```

This means that the probability that strategy beats random in all four card games is basically zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think that I have cause some confusion with my attempt. The target is not to find the probability that a player performs better than random guesser in all the types of game simultaneously. The idea is to look at these four games as one and get the probability that the player will be more successful than random guesser in this joint game.

Comment: You can combine all the games into one and do the analysis as if it was one game only: (895+634 + 315+523) wins in (1080+ 988 +1035 + 975) games. Just drop the last 4 lines of the R code. But this drowns out the bad performance in game 3 will good performance in 1, 2, and 4, and returns a probability of 1. I don't think there is any way to aggregate this data across games without running into this issue.

Comment: I used the formula for the calculation of Posteriors and find something counterintuitive. If we take, for example, 1000 historical random games only 1 of which was won, and a Player that won 0 out of 10 games we will receive a probability of ~0.978 that the player is better than random even though we have no evidence that he can win at least one game. Can you please comment on this, because I started to apply this formula to tasks similar to this and now I am confused and not sure if this is correct?